# How can I know the currently attached volumes in linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I am using an ubuntu EC2 amazon machine. I need to know the currently attached volumes. I used the following command:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

But, I get: cat: proc/partitions: No such file or directory. When I checked proc directory, I found it empty. How can I figure out the currently attached volumes and their names ?

Answer (score 4):

To get proc file system you might need to mount it.

```
mount proc /proc
```

To get list of partitions I use following commands. Each of them gives list of partitions.

```
fdisk -l 
parted -l
df -h
mount
```

Note: `mount` only displays list of volumes currently mounted and `df` shows statistics of mounted volumes.